# How to merge the continues values in rdd after splitting with ":"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an input data like below in a textfile,

states : NY ST UU II EE PP
          UT PP MU ER WE UY EW

REGION code : 02 08 06 87 
               03 99 34 67 23

Here problem is after splitting the key value with ":", am not getting the continued values.

So how to take the continue values into same key.

Like,

**state**

> NY ST UU II EE PP UT MM MU ER WE UY EW

Please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you share you input sample and expected output?

Comment: input data:

plr :  P01 Q53 ZZL Q05  
ilr :  I01 I02 I03 I15 I04 I06 I07 I08 I09 //n
 J10 I02 U65 U51 U52 J07 U55 I95
vc:   AA  BB  SS  CC  DD  HH  HG  JJ  UU //n
 ZA  ZZ  PD  CD  CH  DNC HNC

am  going to split the ilr with ":" so that i will get the key valaue pairs .

but ilr having continues values in the next line.

i want to add the ontinues values to ilr.

And finally expected data looks like,

ilr:I01 I02 I03 I15 I04 I06 I07 I08 I09 J10 I02 U65 U51 U52 J07 U55 I95
vc:AA  BB  SS  CC  DD  HH  HG  JJ  UU ZA  ZZ  PD  CD  CH  DNC HNC

Comment: edit your question with proper explanation and expectations. Thanks